# Quick question about using inline background SVGs

Tags: html, css, svg, background

I am trying to use an inline SVG as a background, but so far have been unable to get it to work. I read a few stackoverflow posts and [this](https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/) css-tricks article on how to do it but I can't get it to work :(

I am trying to use a simple "X" SVG as a CSS background value following the instructions provided in the css-tricks article but clearly I am doing something wrong because nothing appears on my page. Below is a snippet of my code.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.container {
 background:url('data:image/svg+xml,utf-8,<svg stroke="%23fff" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><path d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30"></path></svg>');
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <!-- <svg stroke="#fff" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><path d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30"></path></svg> -->
</body>
</html>
```

I left the SVG in the HTML file commented out. If you uncomment it, you can see the SVG works fine when I use it normally (as an HTLM element). It is only when I use it as a CSS background that it breaks down. I tried encoding it using the base64 encoding website because I read that that fixed the problem for some people, but it didn't work for me. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I know this is probably a stupid question, so I apologize for that. Thanks in advance to anyone who helps!

Comment: is there a specific reason not to convert it into an external svg file and include it as simple background image?

Comment: Not really. I just wanted to use it as an inline SVG because I wanted to learn how to do it this way. I also read that it's more customizable and thought that it'd be a good idea to learn know how to do it this way in case I ever needed to customize a background SVG .

Comment: Ok I'm going to embarrass myself here, but how would clearing my cache make a difference? I really don't know much lol.

Comment: you need to add the namespace: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` : `.container {
 background:url('data:image/svg+xml,utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="black" viewBox="0 0 40 40" width="40"><path d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30"></path></svg>');`

Comment: Thanks @enxaneta that soled it for me! I knew it was probably gonna be a dumb mistake like that, but I couldn't figure it out lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one typo, and one missing namespace definition:

**wrong:**
`data:image/svg+xml,utf-8,<svg stroke="%23fff"`

**right  :**  `data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="%23fff"`

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.container {
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="%23fff" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><path d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30"></path></svg>');
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90vw;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know you had to include that, rookie mistake.

Comment: Only in datauri's (in modern browsers)

Answer (score -1):

body { background-image: url("")}